# What to avoid when buying a domain name?

Tags: domain

I'm in the process to buy a domain name for myself.

What pitfall could I face to ?

If I choose a private registration, will I have full control of my domain ? (host, resell it...)

Will I get alot of spam if I chose a public registration ? All sellers want to sell it and two  of their argument are spam and privacy...

What else do I have to consider ?

---

EDIT

I found [this interesting link](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/wiki/Private_domain_registration).

Except the private/public aspect, is there any other considerations ?

Comment: If you're tempted to buy from GoDaddy: Just say no

Comment: @MikePennington i've had no problems with godaddy domains.  Why do you recommend against them?

Comment: @Grant GoDaddy may be technically fine as a registrar among other services offered, but the company has, as of this comment, positioned itself as an enemy of internet freedom.

Comment: Can you point us to a website explaining this topic with more details, Wesley?

Comment: @Valentin https://www.google.com/search?q=godaddy+sopa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly I don't see any pitfall at all if you have a good spam filter :)

Sure you can go for the private registration which is just a legal way how to hide data from the whois servers, but honestly I never bother with that and I believe I don't have less or more spam/scam attempt because of that. I am not a lawyer, but as I understand you can still cancel, sell, renew or transfer your domain.

For me the only important think is that I am able to freely control my DNS records, even some non standard one like TXT, TTL, etc. This is why I use my own DNS server to control my domain.

If you don't have the access to your own DNS servers just look for a provider, which has a good control panel.